# How to use PnP caching when fetching folders or files Sharepoint picture library?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, react, caching

Caching is working for other calls like for getting items from lists. But I am facing problem when I am trying to use caching when fetching folders and files from sharepoint picture library. PnP call is like this-

```
await sp.web.lists
.getByTitle("Test")
.rootFolder.folders()
.then((resp) => {
   console.log(resp);
});
```

How to use `usingCaching()` for these types of calls?
I tried using after `getFolderByServerRelativePath(folderUrl)` and `rootFolder`, that didnt work.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Its not supported for files and folders

Comment: Okay. Then is there any other way we can implement caching here?